# MySQL: managing user billing and shipping addresses

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

At first I thought it would be good to have an `addresses` table in order to keep track of a users billing and shipping addresses... these of course will be used for orders, etc.

But once I started coding, I noticed that I would have to be able to reference and keep track of those `id` when the user updates them, and for the options "Shipping is the same as my billing address", I would then need to update the reference to the shipping_id as the billing_id ...

I hope what I'm saying makes sense...

I'm now thinking that I should have both the billing and shipping fields within my `user` table or create a `user_details` table.

The actual question is, what is the preferred (or suggested) method(s) of storing and managing a users billing and shipping addresses.

Comment: so what is the actual question?

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a addresses table that contains a flag what indicates the type of address

```
id | user_id | street | number | zip | city | address_type | valid_since | valid_until
```

Comment: Well, this is kind of what I'm doing already and I just feel like there are too many ways to mess up the reference.

Comment: address_type with 1 (shipping) or 2(billing) would be more efficient ?

Comment: @Dagon: Yes, it would.

Comment: Yes, but when a user checks "same as billing", I need to then grab the id of their current billing address, etc, etc... and what if their account is new and they don't yet have a billing address... it's just so much easier to have columns attached to the user.

Comment: @dcolumbus many sites allow users to store multiple addresses.

Comment: not sure you are really describing a problem you have, as opposed to the concern that this could be difficult

Answer (score 0):

You could make a table of addresses for everyone, which holds all the address details plus a user id so they can be linked to a user. This allows any user to have as many addresses as they want. Then in the users table, you could have a field for shipping_address and billing_address which takes an id for a reference in the addresses table. Remember to use foreign keys where appropriate.

If you want an easy way to access user details with useful address info via code, you may want to create a stored procedure to fetch information on both tables

Comment: This is what I currently have. I just don't like the fact that the billing and shipping aren't static ... it's just a bunch of `id`s. What would be the best way to deal with the "same as billing address" option you often see on websites?